# Almost surely return to zero of a random walk

Tags: probability-theory

I have a sequence of bernouilli random variables where $\mathbb{P}(X_n=1)=p$ and $\mathbb{P}(X_n=-1)=1-p$ with $0<p<1$ and $p\neq 1/2$.
Now $S_0=0$ et $S_n=X_1+...+X_n$.
Let's define $A_n=\{S_n=0\}$. How can I prove $\{\lim \inf A_n^\complement\}$ has probability 1?

Comment: Use law of large numbers.

Comment: I think you should double check your statement of this problem.  You have $\mathbb{P}(X_n = 1) = p$ and $\mathbb{P}(X_n = 1) = 1-p$, which can only happen if $p = \frac 12$.  It would also help to add some context to the problem, including what you've tried and any relevant definitions.  In particular, what it means for a sequence of sets to converge almost surely.

Comment: Thanks for your remark, I edited the text : it was $\mathbb{P}(X_n=-1) = 1-p$

Comment: What do you want to prove exactly?

Comment: I am currently studdying almost certain convergence, probability convergence, Borel-Cantelli lemmas, laws of large number,...

Comment: I don't know how to start the problem. I tought about using Borel-Cantelli lemmas, but I'm lost. Also, I don't know how to use laws of large numbers with this problem.

Comment: @AlbertDurand as stated (i.e. "prove $A_n$ is converting almost surely"), it's difficult to understand what you are asking. Do you mind rephrasing your question? Also, note that you must have $p=0.5$ if you want the walk to "almost surely return to zero"

Comment: The original question is "prove that $\mathbb{P}(\overline{\lim} A_n)=0$

Comment: When $p \neq 1/2,$ almost surely, there is an index $n_0$ such that if $n > n_0$ then $S_n \notin A_n.$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will write an answer to my question :

$Y_1+Y_2+\cdots+Y_n=0$ if there are as many $Y_i=1$ as $Y_j=-1$. So there must be an even number of elements. So if $n=2k+1$, with $k \in \mathbb{N}$, we have,
$$\mathbb{P}(A_{2k+1})=0$$

Let's examine the odd case, $n=2k$, $k \in \mathbb{N}$. We have:
$$\mathbb{P}(A_{2k})= {2k \choose k}p^k(1-p)^k$$

To check the convergence :
$$
\frac{\mathbb{P}(A_{2k+2})}{\mathbb{P}(A_{2k})}= \frac{{2k+2 \choose k+1}p^{k+1}(1-p)^{k+1}}{{2k \choose k}p^k(1-p)^k}=\frac{(2k+1)(2k+2)}{(k+1)^2}p(1-p)
$$

But
$\lim_{k\to +\infty} \frac{(2k+1)(2k+2)}{(k+1)^2}p(1-p) = 4p(1-p)<1$ because $p\neq 1/2$.

Using d'Alembert rule,  $\sum\mathbb{P}(A_n)$ converges and using Borel-Cantelli lemma :

$$ \mathbb{P}(\overline{\lim} A_n)=0$$
or
$$ \mathbb{P}(\underline{\lim} A_n)=1$$

There will be almost surely a finite number of returns to zero.

Thanks everybody for your help.